# Sitecore.context.item is null in sitecore 9 custom form submit action?

Tags: sitecore-api, sitecore-forms

I created a item in sitecore and added sitecore 9 forms rendering to that item.

I have created custom form submit action and saved data to custom database.

In my custom save i have used

```
customData.Product_Interest__c= Sitecore.Context.Item?.DisplayName;
```

for getting context item . But I always receiving null.

Any thing missed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed by unchecking the Is Ajax checkbox in Forms.

[image]